# Share filter / predicate between Rx and EF

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, signalr, system.reactive

I want to share a predicate between Rx and EF, without breaking the ability to generate efficient SQL code for the predicate. **Is this possible?**

The ideal solution requires minimal code that does all the following:

- gets entities matching a filter from an entity set
- observes the entity set for changes matching the same filter
- reuses the filter code for both the above
- performs the initial filter at the database
- catches all changes (e.g. [Merging historical and live stock price data with Rx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813963/merging-historical-and-live-stock-price-data-with-rx?rq=1))

In my imagination, the code would look very simple:

```
public IObservable<Pet> GetAndObserveUserPets(int userId) {
    return EfContext.Pets.AsQueryableObservable().Where(d => d.OwnerId == userId);
}
```

Obviously, the central method in the above operation, `AsQueryableObservable()`, does not exist. In practice, I suspect this may not be supported with available software. There may not be a way to "synchronize" the use of "LINQ to Observables" (Rx) and LINQ to Entities (or LINQ to SQL). An additional complication may arise when inspecting related entities in observation predicates, although this may be strictly a design-to-performance concern.

Is there some way to do this?

My goal is to build real-time multi-user web interfaces that display editable information from an SQL database, filtered for usability or security reasons. I expect to use SignalR.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242971(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: I am trying to understand the question. Can I say that your goal is to return an `IObservable<Pet>` that if you subscribed to will give you matching pets that exist currently in the database, but that will also give you new pets that will be added to the database at a later point in time?

Comment: Yes, exactly, Yacoub Massad (as well as provide observation of updates, not just inserts). That would be ideal. However, I would be satisfied with any technique that yields a single-point-of-truth for the related predicates in my code, which in most cases are identical for the initial query and the following observation. My main issue is not duplicating potentially complex business logic.

Comment: So, if we forget about RX for a moment and consider only the data query side of this, how would you know if an entity was updated since the last time you obtained it? Are you going to re-query all the entities that you already obtained to know if they were updated? Or maybe update a timestamp every time you update an entity so that you can obtain updated entities with a simple query?

Comment: That's a great question Yacoub. Initially, with the middle tier running on a single server rather than cluster, the only changes would arrive through the same data service layer that responded to the initial query. Unless I'm mistaken, the EntityFramework.Rx library leans on this to provide observation of changes. (but I'm still exploring all of this)